# Summing up values of a calculated field on MS Access report

Tags: database

On a MS Access report,
I have a calculated textbox field with control source as below:

```
=([PartsTotal]/[GroupTotal])*DateDiff("m",[ReceivedDate],[Forms]![frm_Inventory Reports]![DateTo])
```

It's comparing two dates to get number of months then multiplying it by a percentage `([PartsTotal]/[GroupTotal])`,
to calculate aging of inventory lots.
The name of the calculated textbox control is txtAge.
And I'm trying to sum the values of the calculated field at a group footer.  I tried setting the control source for the other field to:

```
=sum(Me.txtAge)
=sum(Reports!rptName!txtAge)
=sum(([PartsTotal]/[GroupTotal])*DateDiff("m",[ReceivedDate],[Forms]![frm_ Inventory Reports]![DateTo]))
```

None of it works.  Anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Define `None of it works`. Are you getting errors? The data is wrong? Also, shouldn't you have `=Sum(Me.txtAge.Value)` at the footer? I think the `Me.txtAge` is referencing the object and not the value.

Comment: "Enter Parameter Value (Me.txtAge.value)" dialog box comes up.  It does not seem to recognize any of the reference methods above.

Comment: I did a test and referencing control on open form does work within the Sum so your last version should work.

Comment: Thanks.  Mine is report though.  I did initially create the report with the wizard.  Maybe I'll try creating it new from a scratch.

Comment: What do you mean yours is a report? Your expression references a form field. I tested a report with Sum expression referencing form field. Shouldn't matter that report was created with wizard.